# CMD Dir : i can use * instead subfolder

Tags: cmd, directory, subdirectory

This is my tree:

> ```
> f:\mega\user1\rubbish\
> f:\mega\user2\rubbish\
> f:\mega\user3\rubbish\
> .....
> f:\mega\usern\rubbish\
> ```

I would like (ONLY) list all files inside the various "rubbish" folders.

I tried without success this command:

```
DIR F:\mega\*\rubbish\
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this from a cmd.exe prompt.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'F:\mega\*\rubbish'"
```

Of course, it is easier in a PowerShell console or .ps1 file script.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'F:\mega\*\rubbish'
```

Or, possibly this to limit the names to 'user*' subdirectories.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'F:\mega\user*\rubbish'
```

To get only the fully qualified path to the files...

```
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'F:\mega\user*\rubbish').FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

[Wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) can only be used in the *last* element of a path but not somewhere else.

You could however use a [`for /D` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) to resolve the sub-directories:

```cmd
for /D %I in ("F:\mega\user*") do @dir "%~I\rubbish"
```

To use that code in a batch file do not forget to double the `%`-signs:

```cmd
for /D %%I in ("F:\mega\user*") do @dir "%%~I\rubbish"
```